# CMS for intranet use with AD authentification

Tags: cms, active-directory

We are currently using an old version of Typo3, communicating with the AD server via an LDAP extension. We wanted to upgrade to Typo3 8 LTS but ran into problems because includeLibs() was dropped and we were making liberal use of it. Converting the php pages that were 'included' to extensions is not feasible.

Is there a (current) CMS that can authenticate front end users at our AD (LDAP or Kerberos?), manage the user's access to content depending on their group and allows for self written php pages to be included?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CMS like [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) for this.

1. The [LDAP](https://www.drupal.org/project/ldap) module will enable login using AD/LDAP accounts.
2. Users and be put into groups using "roles", to manage their content
3. Depending on complexity of php, you can either create module for it, or enter via a simple page (although the latter option is discouraged due to hassle of managing all such pages).